# jQuery won't return selected value in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I have what seemed to be a simple task. Get `select` value with jQuery. Simple way would be

```
jQuery('#select').val();
```

And this works in Chrome. But when I move to Firefox and do

```
console.log(jQuery('#select').val());  // result => ""
```

I get an empty string. I've tried `jQuery('#select option:selected').val();` and this also works with Chrome, but Firefox still returns empty string.

This select is generated by jquery-ui autocomplete and it has structure like this

```
<select id="select" class="js-SelectList" name="selSelect" style="display:none;">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Apple"></option>
    <option value="Microsoft" selected="selected"></option>
    <option value="Google"></option>
</select>
```

When I add value to first option and I get it's value, so aside from Microsoft option being selected, jQuery in Firefox still regards first option as selected.

Any idea why

Comment: It works for me using `jquery 1.9.1` on both chrome and firefox, see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/92k1gth5/

Comment: Mine is v2.1.3 that came with Zurb Foundation

Comment: Unless the JQuery from Zurb Foundation is nor overriden somehow, this will definitely work. Check the developer console of Firefox for any errors. See what is shown in the dropdown in FF. is "Microsoft" selected?